# A group of n people, let k be an integer 1 ≤ k ≤ n, consider a circular table with k chairs around it,select k people and seat them around this table.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have forgotten a lot of the counting portion of my discrete structures course and need some explanations how to count, maybe some general strategies on counting.

8. Consider a group of n people, let k be an integer with 1 ≤ k ≤ n, and consider a circular
   table with k chairs around it. We select k people and seat them around this table. How
   many different seating arrangements are there? (Two seating arrangements A and B are the
   same if for each person, the clockwise neighbor in A is the same as the clockwise neighbor
   in B, and the counterclockwise neighbor in A is the same as the counterclockwise neighbor
   in B.)

(a) $\frac{n!}{k(n−k)!}$

(b) $\frac{n!}{k!(n−k)!}$

(c) $\frac{n!}{(n−k)!}$

(d) $\frac{2·n!}{(n−k)!}$

I think it is B

If anyone can help explain these questions to me that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't someone answer your question on this last night? I couldn't find your thread, so I'll give it a go.

We start by choosing our $k$ representatives: $\binom{n}{k}$. We then fix the first person. There are $(k-1)!$ ways of permuting the remaining folks, as we differentiate between the left and right neighbors. So by rule of product, we multiply $\binom{n}{k} * (k-1)!$ to get answer (a).

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be a.

The number of ways to seat k of n people in a straight line would be nPr(n,k), which is n!/(n-k)!

But at a circular table, there are k equivalent seats (everybody could just scoot over a seat and nothing changes.  you could do this k ways).  So divide by another k to get n!/k(n-k)!